# I have SQL Server Management Studio 18 - Where I can find SQLServerManager / SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to install SQL Server Configuration Manager in order to configure SQL Aliases, but I don't want to install whole SQL Server

I expected it to be installed with SSMS, but I'm unable to find anything on disk with name `SQLServerManager`

How can I get it as easily(without installing heavy components) as possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded SQL Server *year* Dev (generally not minimal, Express version)
which had a lot of features to choose from, so I was able to install thing called  `Client Tools Connectivity` which allowed me to open `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Answer (score 0):

To configure SQL client aliases, there is no need for SQL Server Configuration Manager. The aliases are often for client-side usage, so installing the Configuration Manager would be extra hoop to jump through. There are two executables called `cliconfg.exe` in `c:\windows\syswow64` and `c:\windows\system32`. These should be present after installing SQL Server Client tools or, in your case, SSMS.

The system32 version of `cliconfg` will create aliases for 64 bit applications, whilst syswow64 does the same for 32 bit. It is a good practice to create aliases for both environments, even if one uses mainly x64. If 32-bit aliases are omitted, legacy applications cannot connect to the database via alias.

For scripted solutions, one can edit registry keys directly. The keys are in paths

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client
```

There are [several](https://dbafromthecold.com/2017/03/29/using-sql-client-aliases/) pages how to [configure](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-server-alias/) aliases (search for `network utility` on the latter link). Googling for `sql server client alias` provides a lot of hits about the subject too.

Comment: I couldnt find 'cilconfg.exe' and Registry solution didn't work, for some reason. I used it before on Win7, but on Win10 it didnt work.

Comment: It is cliconfg.exe. Note the spelling.

Comment: The answer has `cilconfg.exe` once, so that's probably what misled you. I can't do a two-character edit, but if someone can think of other useful edits, they can fix the typo at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to add SQL Server Configuration Server is:

1 - Start —> Run —> mmc.exe

2 - In Menu Bar —> File —> Add/Remove Snap-in (or CTRL + M)

3 - Add SQL Server Configuration Manager and click OK

Comment: In step 3, SQL Server Configuration Manager was not one of the available snap-ins for me.